# ImportXML with XPath in Google Spreadsheet using <span> element

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to get the value of an element attribute from this [site](https://www.romexchange.com/?q=steel) via importXML in Google Spreadsheet using XPath.

The attribute value i seek is `content` found in the `span class="item-chart_server-price__1r2rn"`.
outputs is `2,427 Z`

**Tried using:**

- `//*[@id='app']/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]`  i get #N/A;
- `//div[@id='app']//div[@class='item-chart_item-chart__3YMlA']//div[@class='item-chart_server__37cgg']/span[@class='item-chart_server-price__1r2rn']`  i get #N/A;
- `//span[@class='item-chart_server-price__1r2rn']` i get #N/A;

Answer (score 0):

looks like this won't be possible. all you can get is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.romexchange.com/?q=steel","//*")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I was not able to fetch the data using `ImportXML`, but I ended up being able to fetch from romexchange.com using a custom javascript function.

You can have a look at it in 
https://github.com/diogovk/rom_exchange_sheets_macro/blob/master/rom_exchange_sheets_macro.js

To enable it on your sheets, go to Tools->Script editor.
After you saved a new function `ROMX_latest` will be available.